# Google Forms Response - Date Formatting always in INT instead of Date Format

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I currently have a google form with 1 field for `submission date`. In the form response google sheet I have created a new column for `due date` which is `submission date + 10 Days`.

The formula I have for due date is `ARRAYFORMULA(if(D2:D<>"",TO_DATE(D2:D+10),""))` where Column D is the submission date.

The problem is whenever a new entry is created in the form, the calculated field always returns the **date value** rather than **the readable formatted date**. E.g. returns **4476** rather than **25/09/2021**

Is there a way to enforce formatting on new entries?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to add additional computational columns to the form data intake sheet. This is never a good idea, as it most often wreaks havoc. Standard practice is never to alter your form data intake sheet in any way, but rather to set up a second sheet to further process data, add columns, etc. If you do so, you can easily set the column formatting in that second sheet. If you would like help setting that up, share a link to your sheet (or to a copy of it) with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Solved: ```=ArrayFormula(to_date(IF(isblank(D2:D),,int(D2:D)+10)))```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(IF(isblank(D2:D),,int(D2:D)+10)))
```